# linux monitoring user accounts by last login, home directory and group

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I created a script called monitornsuaccounts.sh that should append its output file to useraccountstatus.log. useraccountstatus.log is in the directory /var/local/nsu/logs/. The output of this script should state every username and the following information about each username: username, last login, user home directory and associated groups. Preferably there should be columns with each information. This is what I have so far but I am having a hard time collecting each username and including the information about each user. The awk definitely works as far as listing all the usernames and each command works individually(like lastlog username) but not when trying to get it from each user account.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F':' '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd > usernames.txt
names=cat usernames.txt|while read usernames; do echo “$usernames”; done
lastlg=cat usernames.txt|while read usernames; do echo “lastlog $usernames”; done
directory=cat usernames.txt|while read usernames; do echo “eval echo ~$usernames”; done
group=cat usernames.txt|while read usernames; do echo “groups $usernames”; done
final=echo “$names | $lastlg | $directory | $group” > /var/local/nsu/logs/useraccountstatus.log
```

Comment: First, get rid of the smart quotes, that's going to kill you.  Then, can you please edit the question to show what your expected output would be?  Also, to run a command and capture the output in a variable use `var=$(cmd...)`, you are missing the `$` parens, so you're not going to actually be saving the values into variables.  Finally, you needn't cat a file into a `while` loop, after `done` you can just redirect the file, like `done < usernames.txt`

Comment: @Daniel: Please show us sample Input_file and expected output.